# Simple PHP if to add shipping cost to price in wp all import, need a little change to PHP IF

Tags: php, if-statement

Ill explain my necessity:

I use wp all import to add product to my store, so some items price's is < 20 euro, in this case ill pay 3 euro for single order as shipping fee.

I need a simply if statements like this

```
[IF({price[.>20]})]{
   price[1]}
[ELSE]{
   price[1]}+3
[ENDIF]
```

That add 3 in case product price is less than 20...but when i try prices becomes not 3+3=6 but 3+000 = 3000

any ideas about?

Comment: Where is the PHP? What you wrote is nowhere near PHP.

Comment: is IF STATEMENT OF wp all import sorry

Comment: https://gist.github.com/m-thomson/982adf4d7f680887f03658949b283096/3eb95b6ea31e89f012c7bc2ef0f7002b53ac1062#number-is-greater-than

Comment: Please check my answer below. It works. I have tested it. Please accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is a little confusing. So I'm going to say what I think you are trying to do.

You have a store and you can add products.

When you are shipping products, if the product's price is less than 20 euros, then add 3 euros as a shipping fee.

In that case, the if-state should be something like:

If you a `product` object with a property `price`...

```
$cost = $product->price; //Get product price
if($product->price < 20){ //If shipping fee needs to be applied
   $cost += 3; //Applied shipping fee
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/m-thomson/982adf4d7f680887f03658949b283096/3eb95b6ea31e89f012c7bc2ef0f7002b53ac1062#number-is-greater-than

Comment: of course! but only thing i need is that {price[1]}+3 is for example 6...like 3+3 and not 3000 as it actual is! My problem is that this functions not add value but only 3 ZERO to original value

Comment: oh i see the problem now... Unfortunately that XPath stuff looks a lot more complex and is something I've never seen before.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I will post the answer in case someone need this is in the future.

When you use Wp All Import you can use [php functions](http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/execute-php/).

In your case you need a function that check the original price and if it is lower than 20 it will add 3, else it will leave it as is.

So that function will look like this:

```
function price_change($originalprice) {
if ($originalprice < "20"):
    $x = abs($originalprice + 3);
else:
    $x = originalprice;
endif;
return $x;
}
```

And then in the price field you should use this:

```
[price_change({price[1]})]
```

It works! I have tested it on my [woocommerce store](https://texas.gr)